# issue while making a 301 redirect to the site home page from custom route in an asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have implemented the 301 permanent redirect as read in [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/108/Handling-Legacy-URLs-with-ASP.NET-MVC) article,

Everything is working except in one case the redirect happens to

```
www.sitename.com/www.sitename.com.
```

It seems like the place where i am trying to redirect is getting appended to the sitename.I want that to happen that when i am trying to redirect to controller action but not when i am redirecting to the site home.

For eg when i do this ,redirect occurs to the

```
newUrl = "Blog/TagPosts/" + {tag}
response.RedirectLocation = newUrl;
response.End();
```

`www.sitename.com/blog/tagposts`.This is what i need but when i redirect to

`www.sitename.com` doing this

```
response.Redirect(www.sitename.com);
response.End();
```

the url gets redirected to `www.sitename.com/www.sitename.com`,How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Response.Redirectlocation is absolute URI that is transmitted to the client in the HTTP Location header.  Try redirecting with the fully qualified location **http://** www.sitename.com.